# Change DelegatingResultSet into Iterable List

Tags: java, jstl, resultset

Basically I am trying to send a ResultSet variable from the Controller to the jsp page and iterate it using the forEach for jstl.   Below is the Controller ResultSet code:

```
String sql = "{call GetDIF_List()}";

        CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        request.setAttribute("recordSet", rs);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/dif/list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

That is returning a "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet" type when trying to call it in the jsp file with the forEach which does not have a .rows attribute like you would get using the sql:query in jstl.

JSP File Code snippet:

```
    <%
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet drs = (org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet)request.getAttribute("recordSet");
while (drs.next())
{
    out.println(drs.getString("DIF_Name") + "<br/>");
}
%>

<table>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${recordSet.rows}">
    <tr><td><a href="/DI_MVC/DIFController?action=edit&id=${item.DIF_ID}">${item.DIF_Name}</a></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

As you can see above, using the scriptlets tags and casting my request object variable to the DelegatingResultSet gets me the results I want.  Though I want to do the more standard approach of using jstl and the forEach but the recordSet variable does not have a .rows or something similar to use to iterate through it.  Unless I am overlooking it.

Thank you for any suggestions or help.

Comment: I was able to get the iteration going in the jsp file for the jstl forEach.  I am not too thrilled with it because I basically had to iterate through the recordset in the controller and add the items to a generic list with the type of the class I created.  Than I iterated through that generic list with the forEach loop.

Comment: The only reason I mentioned I wasn't too thrilled with that solution was because it was double work with the iterating through the results just to keep it standardized to using jstl.  Where as scriptlets allowed one loop, which in a larger application, would seem to have better performance advantages.  Maybe spring, struts, hibernate or others will have better solutions once I dive into them more.